# Spigen USB-C Cable doesn't fit MacBook Pro (13", 2019)

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I have a [Spigen cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Spigen-Essential-C20CH-Thunderbolt-Smartphones/dp/B0791DC4NP) that doesn't fit my MacBook Pro. I try to insert it but still doesn't work. This cable fits my usb-c powerbank and my old Dell laptop. It looks like there is a difference between MBP Charger plug and my HDMI-USBC plug. Is this issue common? Is there a way to solve this issue? Maybe it's a production defect.

Edit **13.05.2020**:

[image: Ports]

[image: Plugs]

Comment: *Is there a way to solve this issue?*. Besides getting a different cable/adapter, I’m not sure what your expectations are here.  If it doesn’t fit,  it doesn’t fit.  Though you didn’t say exactly how it didn’t fit....too big, too small, etc.

Comment: @Allan Yeah I wrote this in a hope that there is some magical solution.

Comment: Posting photos won't help; unless you've got a caliper or similar tool to actually measure them - you're not going to see thousandths of an inch difference with the naked eye.  What you need to do is get other USB-C devices and plug them into both your MacBook and Dell laptop.  If other devices work, then it's the Spiegen that's out of spec.  If you have difficulty with other adapters on your MacBook then the MacBook has the issue.  If that's the case, it needs to go back because the port is out of spec and not something you can fix.

Comment: @Allan Yeah, I think that there is no resolution for this issue other than buying new cable.

Answer (score 2):

The 2019 13" MacBook Pro has a completely standard Thunderbolt 3 port, which physically is the same form factor as USB-C. It's not a "charger plug" as such, but a generic port that supports power, data and alternate mode (display signal).

The Spigen cable has a USB-C plug in one end and a HDMI plug at the other end. It is the USB-C end of the cable that you're meant to plug into the MacBook Pro. If you cannot physically make it fit, contact the vendor that sold you the cable.

Spigen lists their cable as being USB-C, which means that it should in any case fit. In addition they specifically list the 2016 MacBook Pro and later versions as being compatible with their cable.

Comment: Just like I wrote in original post, It works with different devices that support USB-C. There must be something wrong with the form of a plug (or socket in MBP). I don't think anything will help here.

Comment: Could you take a picture of the port on the MacBook Pro and add to the question? Perhaps look if dust or similar got into the plug, blocking the cable you’re trying to connect?

Comment: It is brand new device, there is no dust inside, I could take the photo comparing two plugs. One of apple charger and one of spigen cable.

Comment: Please do add a photo of both cable and computer port. Most likely you’re either mistaken about the kind of port you have, or the device is damaged somehow.

Comment: @TomaszKasperek Is the problem with _all_ ports on the MacBook Pro? or just one of them?